# How to wait for a future before rendering anything?

Tags: flutter, future

Here's my problem :

I test the existence of a currentUser in an AppModel using Provider lib to know if my app's scaffold will show Homepage or LoginPage this way :

```
void main() async {
  // Hive initialization ::
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(document.path);
  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (c) => AppModel()),
        Provider(create: (c) => UserDao()),
        ...
      ],
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: '_',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: AppScaffold()
        );
      }),
    );
  } // build()
}// MyApp

class AppScaffold extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AppScaffoldState createState() => _AppScaffoldState();
}

class _AppScaffoldState extends State<AppScaffold> {

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    GetUserFromDB().run();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Bind to AppModel.currentUser:
    User? currentUser = context.select<AppModel, User?>((value) => value.currentUser);
    return Scaffold(
      body: currentUser != null ? HomePage(title: 'HomePage') : LoginPage(title: 'LoginPage'),
    );
  }
}
```

Therefore my problem is that, once the user is logged a first time, when i kill and reopen the app this happens ::

- The app opens
- Then shows for 1second or less the LoginPage (which i don't want !)
- Finally and rapidly go to Homepage when the Future 'GetUserFromDB()' updates the appModel's currentUser

My problem is that i DON'T WANT the user to see the loginPage, even briefly, before going to homepage when already connected...

I tried to use FutureBuilder but same result
The problem seems to be that i don't have the user from DB soon enough
But where | How to catch it before, knowing i can't do it before the

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
```

is done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i finally did find a workaround this way ::

i moved the

> Phoenix() // Allows to restart the app from wherever via
> Phoenix.rebirth()

from "MyApp" to "MaterialApp".

That allowed me to instantiate the AppModel directly into the main method and thus,to have the future's answer soon enough not to display the login page, even brievly, before the homepage when already connected...

Indeed the problem came when i developed the logout feature 'cause Phoenix do ".dispose()" all the provided Models|Controllers|Daos|Services using provider lib...
Therefore, when you did reconnect without killing the app first, Flutter did launch an exception telling you can't use a Model after it was disposed...

Answered in case this could be usefull to someone else ^^

PS :: @harsha.kuruwita
thanks for your answer but couldn't use the splashScreen since i made the choice to override the white Flutter native one thanks to the

> flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.4

lib that i recommend ^^
this way you :

- don't spend time over 2 splashscreens
- and since the native one can't be avoided >> it allows you to personnalize and make it "cooler" for the user ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use splash screen to user check logic , best practises is keep your user model in internal db like SharedPreferences or hive db

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await HiveConfig.initHiveDatabase();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<appProvider>(
            create: (context) => appProvider())
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/splash',
        onGenerateRoute: app_route.Router.genarateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  const Splash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<appProvider>(context, listen: false);
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), () async {
      var hiveUserModel = await appRepositories().getHiveUserModel();

      if (hiveUserModel == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/user_login');
      } else {
        provider.setHiveUser(hiveUserModel);
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: appTheamColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Center(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/app_logo.png',
                  scale: 3.4,
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                  child: Text(
                    appVersion,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 11,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```